# How to achieve wifi display after connected by wifi direct

Tags: android, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I want to make a wifi display app on my android phone (HongMi). The android version of my phone is 4.2.2

I modified the example WiFiDirectActivity and tried to combine it with this project [Miracast-Sample](https://github.com/adamrocker/Miracast-Sample).
I know that I need to connect two devices by wifi direct(wifi p2p) before mirroring the screen to another(wifi display).
I do register the DisplayListener in onResume() (and deregister in onPause()).
I also register a BroadcastReceiver to listen to the wifi p2p message.

I can receive the wifi p2p message whenever I connect/disconnect by wifi p2p. But I cannot receive anything with my DisplayListener after connected. My DisplayListener even does not be triggered.

My problem is, after I connected two devices, **how to detect there is a new second screen can be displayed**, or why the DisplayListener doesn't be triggered.

Thanks for help